# same instance being shared across multiple class for a lazy val declared in a trait?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have the tests failing intermittently and after some debugging I am observing that the `spark` val declared in the `trait` is being shared across the two separate suites (came to this conclusion because the same `hashCode` is being printed in `beforeAll` in the log). Sharing here the base classes, 2 test suites and the log. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

When I removed the `var tableDeltaDf: DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame` from `DataValidationTest` and `MetadataTest`, the issue is gone. **I am still not clear on what is happening.**

Base trait and class

```
trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {
      lazy val spark: SparkSession = { SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate() }
    }
    
abstract class SparkTestBaseSpec extends AnyFunSuite
      with SparkSessionTestWrapper with DatasetComparer
      with Logging
      with Matchers with OptionValues with Inside with Inspectors with BeforeAndAfterAll {
      override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
        println("beforeAll spark.hashCode: " + spark.hashCode())
        logInfo("beforeAll spark.isStopped: " + spark.sparkContext.isStopped)
      }

  override protected def afterAll: Unit = {
    println("afterAll spark.hashCode: " + spark.hashCode())
    spark.stop()
    logInfo("afterAll spark.isStopped: " + spark.sparkContext.isStopped)
  }
}
```

**TestSpec 1 & 2**

```
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
    
class MetadataTest extends SparkTestBaseSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {
      var tableDeltaDf: DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame

      override protected def beforeAll: Unit = {
            super.beforeAll()
            tableDeltaDf = createNewDF() //removed the def for brevity
      }
        
       test("test 1") {
        
       }
}
        
class DataValidationTest extends SparkTestBaseSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {
        
var tableDeltaDf: DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame
          
override protected def beforeAll: Unit = {
            super.beforeAll()
tableDeltaDf = createNewDF() //removed the def for brevity
}
        
test("test 2") {
        
}
}
```

**IntelliJ IDEA Log**

```
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='DataValidationTest' locationHint='scalatest://TopOfClass:DataValidationTestTestName:DataValidationTest' captureStandardOutput='true' nodeId='36' parentNodeId='0']
beforeAll spark.hashCode: 2024860730
afterAll spark.hashCode: 2024860730
beforeAll spark.hashCode: 2024860730
##teamcity[message text='Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.|nThis stopped SparkContext was created at:|n|norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:23)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark$(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:10)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark$lzycompute(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.beforeAll(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:18)|nCustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.beforeAll(CustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.scala:17)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|norg.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|nscala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n|nThe currently active SparkContext was created at:|n|n(No active SparkContext.)|n         ' status='ERROR' errorDetails='java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.|nThis stopped SparkContext was created at:|n|norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:23)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark$(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:10)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark$lzycompute(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.beforeAll(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:18)|nCustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.beforeAll(CustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.scala:17)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|norg.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|nscala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n|nThe currently active SparkContext was created at:|n|n(No active SparkContext.)|n         |n   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:118)|n at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2510)|n  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultMinPartitions(SparkContext.scala:2519)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.createBaseRdd(JsonDataSource.scala:188)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.infer(JsonDataSource.scala:161)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource.inferSchema(JsonDataSource.scala:65)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:59)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:210)|n at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)|n  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:207)|n at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)|n    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:405)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:386)|n   at com.tccc.dna.supplychain.cs.files.JsonFile$.readFile(JsonFile.scala:13)|n    at com.tccc.dna.supplychain.cs.init.ApplicationConfig$.loadConfig(ApplicationConfig.scala:18)|n at DataValidationTest.beforeAll(DataValidationTest.scala:21)|n  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|n at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|n   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|n  at com.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|n   at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|n   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|n   at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:798)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)|n   at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)|n at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)|n']

##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='MetaDataTest' locationHint='scalatest://TopOfClass:MetaDataTestTestName:MetaDataTest' captureStandardOutput='true' nodeId='37' parentNodeId='36']
afterAll spark.hashCode: 2024860730
##teamcity[message text='Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.|nThis stopped SparkContext was created at:|n|norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:23)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark$(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:10)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark$lzycompute(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.beforeAll(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:18)|nCustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.beforeAll(CustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.scala:17)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|norg.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|nscala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n|nThe currently active SparkContext was created at:|n|n(No active SparkContext.)|n         ' status='ERROR' errorDetails='java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.|nThis stopped SparkContext was created at:|n|norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:23)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkSessionTestWrapper.spark$(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:10)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark$lzycompute(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.spark(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.beforeAll(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:18)|nCustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.beforeAll(CustomerSatisfactionSparkAppTest.scala:17)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|norg.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|ncom.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|norg.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|nscala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|norg.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n|nThe currently active SparkContext was created at:|n|n(No active SparkContext.)|n         |n   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:118)|n at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2510)|n  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultMinPartitions(SparkContext.scala:2519)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.createBaseRdd(JsonDataSource.scala:188)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.infer(JsonDataSource.scala:161)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource.inferSchema(JsonDataSource.scala:65)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:59)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:210)|n at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)|n  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:207)|n at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)|n    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)|n    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:405)|n   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:386)|n   at com.tccc.dna.supplychain.cs.files.JsonFile$.readFile(JsonFile.scala:13)|n    at com.tccc.dna.supplychain.cs.init.ApplicationConfig$.loadConfig(ApplicationConfig.scala:18)|n at MetaDataTest.beforeAll(MetaDataTest.scala:28)|n  at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:212)|n at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)|n   at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)|n  at com.tccc.dna.synapse.spark.test.SparkTestBaseSpec.run(SparkTestBaseSpec.scala:12)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)|n   at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)|n   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)|n   at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)|n    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:798)|n  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)|n   at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)|n at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)|n']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you call [getOrCreate](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L995) from `SparkSession.Builder`.

```scala
trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = 
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate() // <- here
}
```

If you look at the scaladoc says

```scala
    /**
     * Gets an existing [[SparkSession]] or, if there is no existing one, creates a new
     * one based on the options set in this builder.
     *
     * This method first checks whether there is a valid thread-local SparkSession,
     * and if yes, return that one. It then checks whether there is a valid global
     * default SparkSession, and if yes, return that one. If no valid global default
     * SparkSession exists, the method creates a new SparkSession and assigns the
     * newly created SparkSession as the global default.
     *
     * In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the non-static config options specified in
     * this builder will be applied to the existing SparkSession.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
```

If you want to use a different `SparkSession` you should use [newSession](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L250) where the docs says

```scala
  /**
   * Start a new session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary tables, registered
   * functions are isolated, but sharing the underlying `SparkContext` and cached data.
   *
   * @note Other than the `SparkContext`, all shared state is initialized lazily.
   * This method will force the initialization of the shared state to ensure that parent
   * and child sessions are set up with the same shared state. If the underlying catalog
   * implementation is Hive, this will initialize the metastore, which may take some time.
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
```

your new `SparkSessionTestWrapper` should look like

```scala
trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = 
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .newSession()
}
```

Doing that, your suite tests should use a different session.

Comment: This isn't the issue. After some tests, When I removed the `var tableDeltaDf: DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame` from `Test1` and `Test2`, the issue is gone. Now I am looking for the explanation from experts.

Comment: now I'm confused. You said "spark val declared in the trait is being shared across the two separate suites". Also showed that both `spark: SparkSession` had the same **hashcode**. Now you are saying that removing `var tableDeltaDf` solve that problem?

Comment: yes. it is no longer having the same hashCode. tested it multiple times. Now I am confused about why.